# Xamarin.Forms iOS Entity Framework SQLite exception while creating DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I get this exception when creating an instance of `DbContext`:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key

My `DbContext` file:

```
public sealed class DefectContext : DbContext
{
    //private string _dbPath { get; set; }

    public DbSet<defects> i_defect { get; set; }
    public DbSet<defMods> i_def_mod { get; set; }
    public DbSet<defDescr> i_def_descr { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FotoDefects> i_foto_def { get; set; }

    public DefectContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var dbPath = DependencyService.Get<IPath>().GetDatabasePath(App.DatabaseName);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Для i_defect
        // Определение составного первичного ключа
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().HasKey(p => new { p.c_isso, p.n_def });
        // Определение Nullable полей
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.n_constr).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.b).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.b1).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.d).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.d1).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.r).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.r1).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.g).HasDefaultValue(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.g1).HasDefaultValue(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.datef).IsRequired(false);

        // Для i_def_mod
        modelBuilder.Entity<defMods>().HasKey(p => new {p.c_isso, p.n_def, p.date});
        modelBuilder.Entity<defMods>().Property(p => p.l_def).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defMods>().Property(p => p.w_def).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defMods>().Property(p => p.c_rem).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defMods>().Property(p => p.v_rem).IsRequired(false);

        // Для i_def_descr
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().HasKey(p => new {p.c_isso, p.n_def, p.date, p.c_defparam});
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.value).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.b1).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.d).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.d1).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.r).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.r1).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.g).HasDefaultValue(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.g1).HasDefaultValue(false);

        // Для i_foto_def
        modelBuilder.Entity<FotoDefects>().HasKey(p => new {p.c_isso, p.n_def, date = (DateTime) p.date});
        modelBuilder.Entity<FotoDefects>().Property(p => p.foto).IsRequired(false);

        var dateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, long>(
            // В БД
            v => new DateTimeOffset(v).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(),
            // Из БД
            v => DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(v).DateTime
        );
        var byteArrayConverter = new ValueConverter<byte[], string>(
            // В БД
            v => Convert.ToBase64String(v),
            // Из БД
            v => Convert.FromBase64String(v)
            );

        // Определение конвертации поля в БД
        modelBuilder.Entity<defects>().Property(p => p.date)
            .HasConversion(dateTimeConverter);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defMods>().Property(p => p.date)
            .HasConversion(dateTimeConverter);
        modelBuilder.Entity<defDescr>().Property(p => p.date)
            .HasConversion(dateTimeConverter);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FotoDefects>().Property(p => p.date)
            .HasConversion(dateTimeConverter);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FotoDefects>().Property(p => p.foto)
            .HasConversion(byteArrayConverter);
    }
}
```

Get database path code file:

```
public class IosDbPath : IPath
{
    public string GetDatabasePath(string filename)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", filename);
    }
}
```

And when I go to this line of code:

```
using (var sqliteRepository = new DefectContext()){...}
```

the error occurs.

Can't find any information about why could it happen.

p.s. I'm working with iOS simulator. Please give me some advice...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe caused that you forgot to set `primary key` in model class(defects,defMods,defDescr,FotoDefects).

Add [Key] to the property which qualifies it as the primary key in the corresponding table.

Like

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```